# What is javascript array mutation?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm planning to start a new project on React-Redux. 
I'm not understanding what is array mutation. Can anyone clarify what is array mutation ?

Comment: It is any operation that changes the array.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Mutator_methods

Comment: const heroes = ['Batman'];
let AddedArr =heroes.push('Superman');

//console.log(AddedArr)
console.log(heroes)

Answer (score 4):

Mutation is basically changing the array itself instead of returning a new array with the new changes

for more info: **Check these links:**

https://slemgrim.com/mutate-or-not-to-mutate/

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread